# Using crypt(), how does my app validate passwords that have randomly generated salts?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I've been looking at [PHP's crypt function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) and a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064808/what-is-being-encrypted-when-i-use-a-salted-crypt-md5-to-encrypt-my-password) on Stackoverflow, and I'm trying to figure out salted and hashed passwords.

I found this on the PHP community page:

```
<?php
function md5crypt($password){
    // create a salt that ensures crypt creates an md5 hash
    $base64_alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                    .'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
    $salt='$1$';
    for($i=0; $i<9; $i++){
        $salt.=$base64_alphabet[rand(0,63)];
    }
    // return the crypt md5 password
    return crypt($password,$salt.'$');
}
?>
```

How does something like that compare to:

```
<?php
// Slightly modified example from PHP community page

$password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));

// Get the hash, letting the salt be automatically generated
$hashed_password = crypt($password);
?>
```

Here's an excerpt from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064808/what-is-being-encrypted-when-i-use-a-salted-crypt-md5-to-encrypt-my-password):

> However, the PHP crypt() function can
>   use a variety of different hashes to
>   compute the hash. When you prefix your
>   salt with "$1$" you get a hash with an
>   MD5. When you prefix with $2$ you get
>   a crypt with blowfish, which is more
>   secure.
>
> The "$1$" is prefixed to the output so
>   that the hash can be verified. If it
>   wasn't included, there would be no way
>   to know from the stored hash which
>   algorithm should be used! This
>   information would have to be stored
>   elsewhere. To save you this trouble
>   PHP includes the algorithm in the hash
>   output.

My head is spinning a bit concerning hashes, encryption and salts... but the part that really stumps me, is how do I compare a user-entered `password` against a `salted hashed password`, if the salt is randomly generated upon user creation... and not stored--and on top of that, what's the point of using crypt() with an automated salt, if you HAVE to specify the correct prefix to be able to validate the password again upon user return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the salt with the user.

The purpose of the salt is to ensure that two users with the same password get different hashes.
This prevents rainbow table attacks.

**EDIT**: Your salt should contain (cryptographically-secure-)random *bytes*.
Right now, you're restricting it to only contain letters and numbers

Comment: How would I store it with the user, other than cookies? What were to happen if cookies were to be wiped... they just can't be validated? Also sorry for the noob question, but what is ASCII... or better yet, what's an alternative to ASCII?

Comment: @Julian: In your database table.  I don't mean on the client; I mean along with the rest of your user info.

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought the point of salt was to add an additional layer of security... thus making storing it a backwards move.  So `crypt()` a good choice, but how do I go about creating a random byte salt?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to have a random salt for every user/password.

Adding a salt will just make more difficult to guess your password, but using a random salt for every account will increase the security as it'll reduce the way for an attacker to guess any other passwords, as given some current and unsecure password and/or username, the reverse engineering to guess password would be easy.

It has a big impact on cross-system security as people tends to use the name username/password on most sites.

Using a random salt makes an attack almost impossible with a dictionary as you'll need to compute every salt possible to guess any password.

Comment: So if a user gains access to my database, is 'security' a moot point--or do the salts still help?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the format of /etc/shadow, you'll see the nomenclature in the second field (with `:` delimiting fields):

```
username:${enctype}${salt}$HoPeFuLlYVerYloNGpassWOrDhAsh: ... ... ...
```

The salt is actually stored with the password. `{enctype}` is the type of encryption being employed, `{salt}` is the salt. Since you *know* the encryption type and salt, you can naturally reproduce the hash with the password they provide (thus authenticating the user).

A handy table of `{enctype}` values for crypt (for informational purposes):

```
          ID  | Method
          ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
          1   | MD5
          2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
              | Linux distributions)

          5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
          6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
```

And finally, [how PHP lets you use them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

So, if you see a string like:

```
root:$6$foobar$JKLsdiuoilI/KSJHDKUyjh/SHDKJyUYW(....)
```

You know that you're dealing with SHA-512 and the salt is 'foobar' (and likely, the account is foobar too!).

It is (one) example of how salts are stored and associated with hashes. As [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846293/using-crypt-how-does-my-app-validate-passwords-that-have-randomly-generated-sa/4846318#4846318) said, don't restrict the salt to just ASCII. At the minimum you should be obtaining bytes from a PRNG or HRNG, falling back to time() **only** when no RNG is available.

Answer (score 0):

No, You are doing it wrong. Use solardesigner's [PHPASS](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) in order to do the hashing and validation. Finally, never EVER use your own ad-hoc scheme, doing that is asking for trouble.